# How to execute and run a Trigger as a System Administrator

Tags: apex, trigger, future

To start, I know that you can only use `System.RunAs` with test methods. Now that we got that out of the way, I have a trigger that is executing an operation that the current user can't do with their profile. I would prefer not to edit the validation rule to exempt certain profiles. I have heard that it may be possible accomplishing this by using a future method? Can someone explain how I would go about doing that? Or if there is a better way to do it? Let me know if there is any additional information I can provide to answer the question.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**
I used the info from these links to get the answer. I hope this helps people that stumble on this issue in the future:

- [Make Validation Rule bypass if TRIGGER is run?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/10350/make-validation-rule-bypass-if-trigger-is-run/10353#10353)
- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_custom_settings.htm

Comment: Are you looking for something like this ? http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/64495/preventing-a-class-from-firing-based-on-the-current-user-profile/64499#64499

Comment: I believe you are looking to run a trigger in system mode.  See this post for a lot of insight into it http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/system-mode-or-god-mode-in-apex-gotchas/

Comment: Stephen, can you post the relevant content from those links as a proper answer? It's perfectly ok on SFSE to post and accept an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the info from these links to get the answer. I hope this helps people that stumble on this issue in the future:

- [Make Validation Rule bypass if TRIGGER is run?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/10350/make-validation-rule-bypass-if-trigger-is-run/10353#10353)
- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_custom_settings.htm

Comment: You should add some information in your post about how you solved the issue. Links tend to break over time.